# Get font family name from QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfont

I'm using QFontDatabase:addApplicationFont, and it's working as intended, but I want to get the family font name from the last ttf file it loads up, since the intended use of it is letting the user use whatever font they point towards.

I mostly want to know if this is possible within QFont or if I'll have to rely on a different library for it.

```cpp
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(font_path);
ui_vp_message->setFont(QFont(ttf_font_family_name, f_weight));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the names using the [`QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#applicationFontFamilies) method:

```cpp
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(font_path);
if(id != -1){
    QStringList font_families = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id);
    qDebug()<< font_families;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's definetly in the right direction, but since 
  setfont(QFont(x, y)); 
only admits qstrings, not lists, I tried doing 
  setFont(QFont(font_family.at(0)
which results in a Segmentation fault crash. I fail to understand why, should I be looking for a workaround?

Comment: @Uri Have you done the verifications I use in my code as `if(id != -1)`?

Comment: @Uri I did not observe this problem, in the following link is my test code https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55585443